# What method would I need to use in JDA to check if a message contains an image?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am looking to create a command where you can type in the command with an image and have my bot return a random string answer, what I need to know is what method would I use to check if a message contains an image?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images can be in the message attachments ([Message#getAttachments](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getAttachments())) or in the message embeds ([Message#getEmbeds](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getEmbeds())).

To check if an attachment is an image, use [Attachment#isImage](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.Attachment.html#isImage()). For embeds, images can be provided by multiple components:

- [MessageEmbed#getImage](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageEmbed.html#getImage())
- [MessageEmbed#getThumbnail](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageEmbed.html#getThumbnail())
- [MessageEmbed#getFooter](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageEmbed.html#getFooter())
- [MessageEmbed#getAuthor](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageEmbed.html#getAuthor())

All of these return wrapper objects which provide URLs to the image.